# Access LinkedMDB offline

Tags: semantic-web, dbpedia, linked-data, linkedmdb

I need to carry out an experiment that takes into consideration all movies of LinkedMDB including their predicates. LinkedMDB SPARQL endpoint is not very efficient, it gets overloaded easily and refuse connection after sending about 40 consecutive queries in my Java/Jena program. Therefore I had to stop the execution of the program for two seconds (Thread.sleep) and then continue. I can't do that for more than 90.000 datasets and their predicates. Is their a way or a link where all LinkedMDB movies datasets can be downloaded and accessed locally (I think Geonames have it, not sure about LinkedMDB)

Comment: can I have the endpoint url please ?

Comment: @WilliamKinaan  
www.linkedmdb.org/sparql : accessible via a program (the one I am using in my Java/Jena program)
http://www.linkedmdb.org/snorql: an other interface.

Comment: thanks but I am getting `502 Bad Gateway` I'm being redirected to `http://settlement.cs.toronto.edu:40170/snorql/`

Comment: @WilliamKinaan it was working yesterday night, first time see it happening .

Comment: well ... hopefully they'll fix it soon

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor yes it is a duplicate, but the answer is not valid anymore.  wiki.linkedmdb.org is not working, and the latest RDF dumps in http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~oktie/linkedmdb/ are 2009. But still, I didn't know it exists. that's helpful.